# Register and start BroadcastReceiver from manifest

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to register a BroadcastReceiver in my manifest, but it doesn't happen. After trying to write the xml by hand (and failing), I simply clicked on Eclipse's tools and added my receiver from Eclipse's GUI like this (I didn't write any code by hand):

```
<receiver android:name="MyReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

What I try to do is catch all the BATTERY_CHANGED intents the system sends out. But it simply doesn't start receiving.

Now please tell me, should I add anything to the manifest/receiver/activity code, to get the system to instantiate, and start this receiver to work?

**I don't want to use the `registerReceiver()` function, because I want this receiver to run separately from any activities.**

Comment: `android:name=".MyReciever"`, don't forget the [dot] before the class name that is extended from `BroadcastReceiver`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED) states that `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` **cannot** be registered in the manifest, you must register this from a valid Context inside your Java code.

The good news is that Contexts are found in more than just Activities, if you like you can use registerReceiver() in a Service or anywhere else you have a valid Context.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment, just to say thank you for the information. Finally a clear and helpful answer. Thank you again. I'll accept your answer as soon, as StackOverflow enables it :)